# Small files and hadoop/spark - each original file being a single unit of computation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

### Scenario

I have a scenario where I would like to scalably process data comprising many files of small size (~0.7MB average input file size). As this is not supposed to work with `hdfs` with many small files [due to the "small files problem"](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/), I figure I would merge all input files of one type (lets call it type A) into one hdfs file, and files of another type (lets call it type B) into another hdfs file, and so on.

I need however, in my case, to preserve the relation between an original input file and its content - as each input file should be separately processed as one unit, in map-reduce jobs, in my case, arising from the nature of my data.

### Questions are:

1. How shall I mark the *boundary* of each input file inside the aggregate file it goes to? Ideally I'd organize them as key value pairs, the key being e.g. the original file name, and the value being its content. Hopefully map operations would be able to then seamlessly consume it accordingly - each key-value pair representing an original file. How is that best accomplished?
2. How would I go about the case of *binary* input files, in case that requires special treatment?
3. Assuming files of type B aggregate to one single file as mentioned, and a map operation's goal is simply to create one output of similar size, from each original input file, what would be the best way for creating an aggregate output file C comprising all these outputs? about half my jobs will only do mapping, no reducing...

### Note about Apache Spark

I will likely be using `Apache Spark` jobs and not `hadoop` map reduce jobs. I can still mix between them, e.g. if the initial file aggregation works better with hadoop.

#### Finally

Many answers discuss related aspects but many/most of them are old and not necessarily representing the best ways in today's versions, not to mention ways to do this with `Spark`, or to preserve each original input file as a discrete unit.

Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: I am curious to know if you have arrived at any conclusions regarding handling binary files as discrete units of work. The only approach that seems to fit is writing a custom class extending from `FileInputFormat` that returns a single `InputSplit` representing the entire contents of the file.

Comment: I follow the same line of thought, but have not insofar experimented that part!

Answer (score 0):

Do your files need to be stored on HDFS ? Can you read them from S3? Spark supports reading files from S3 which would allow you to get around this issue.

Comment: Well it seems you have not addressed most of the question... of course the files can be imported.